# Clear render parameters on WebSphere Portal

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, jsr286

I need WebSphere Portal to clear Render Parameters on page change. What's happening now -and it's a Navigational State feature of the product- is that the render parameters that I used in some URL's are being encoded in the URL, so even after I leave the page when I return my render parameters are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some of the options from the link below if you're allowed to create friendly urls or modify the theme navigation to use keepNavigationalState attribute.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21586973

Edit: I looked up the portlet code where I thought I removed parameters from a RenderRequest. I actually was using the PortletSession to move an attribute from a processAction method to the doView. I then removed attribute from the session so it wouldn't be used on a page refresh. It's kind of a hack and you will need to turn on public session to support anonymous users ( http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.exp.doc/wps/srvcfgref.html - Go to Navigator Service) but it's another option to think about.

Comment: And how do I do that? There's no removeParameter method in RenderRequest class

Comment: You're correct. I mis-remembered how I did this previously. I have updated my answer to to reflect that. It's a less than ideal solution than what I thought it was, but it's another option to try.